# find recurring payments that occur within a time frame monthly in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe and i want to find recurring payments for the same id (only if the amount is the same and the day of the month is the same with a margin of error (+-5 days).
I have done the following:

```
d = {'id':[1,1,1,3,3,3,5,5,5],
    'day_of_month':[2,2,5,4,6,8,10,15,25],
    'amount':[1000,1000,50,1500,3000,1500,4000,2000,2000]}
dd = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(dd)
    id  day_of_month    amount
0   1     2            1000
1   1     2            1000
2   1     5             50
3   3     4            1500
4   3     6            3000
5   3     8            1500
6   5     10           4000
7   5     15           2000
8   5     25           2000
```

Then i do this :

```
dd[dd.duplicated(subset = ['id','amount'], keep = False)]
    id  day_of_month       amount
0   1      2                1000
1   1      2                1000
3   3      4                1500
5   3      8                1500
7   5      15               2000
8   5      25               2000
```

As you can see the last row of the output is a false positive as I haven't managed to implement the +-5 day window of the monthday.
My desired output should be this

```
   id       day_of_month    amount
0   1      2                1000
1   1      2                1000
3   3      4                1500
5   3      8                1500
```

Any idea on how to implement what i need? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not add another `mask`?

Your original `mask`:

```
non_duplicates_mask = dd.duplicated(subset = ['id','amount'], keep = False)
```

The months `mask`:

```
months_mask = abs(dd['day_of_month'] - dd['day_of_month'].shift()) >= 5
```

I'm using `abs` just in case the `day_of_month` is not always in an ascending order,

Then apply `xor` operation with both masks:

```
dd[non_duplicates_mask ^ months_mask]
```

output:

```
    id  day_of_month    amount
0   1   2               1000
1   1   2               1000
3   3   4               1500
5   3   8               1500
```

**Edit:**
The `xor` (eXclusive OR) operates like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have never used xor operation before. What exactly is it doing?

Comment: @Unicorn07 I have added a visual representation of `xor`, and **if** the answer did solve your problem, don't forget to upvote & tick the green v :)